# how to integrate facebook messenger in our Single Page Application

Tags: java, angularjs, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a single page application,my front end is in angular and services are in java. I want to send notifications to user on facebook messenger. how to do this??? do i need to create Boat and Webhook .

Comment: What kind of boat are we talking about some sort of destroyer?

Comment: It is facebook messenger bot

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the web plugins, such as send to messenger or customer chat:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin